# Ни одна из перегрузок метода "GlobalMemoryStatusEx" не принимает "9" аргументов. C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string DirectoryName,
           out ulong FreeBytesAvailableToCaller,
           out ulong TotalNumberOfBytes,
           out ulong TotalNumberOfFreeBytes);


         [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GlobalMemoryStatus")]
         static extern void GlobalMemoryStatusEx(out long Length,
           out long MemoryLoad,
           out ulong TotalPhys,
           out ulong AvailPhys,
            out ulong TotalPageFile,
            out ulong AvailPageFile,
            out ulong TotalVirtual,
            out ulong AvailVirtual);




        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ulong TotalNumberOfFreeBytes, TotalNumberOfBytes, FreeBytesAvailableToCaller;
            string disk = @"C:\";
            GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(disk, out FreeBytesAvailableToCaller, out TotalNumberOfBytes, out TotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
            textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0} байт", TotalNumberOfBytes);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uint MemoryLoad, Length, TotalPhys, AvailPhys, TotalPageFile, AvailPageFile, TotalVirtual, AvailVirtual;

            GlobalMemoryStatusEx(disk, out Length, out MemoryLoad, out TotalPhys, out AvailPhys, out TotalPageFile, out AvailPageFile,
                out TotalVirtual, out AvailVirtual); //Тут выдаёт ошибку
            textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0} %", MemoryLoad);



        }

     }          
}
```

Как убрать ошибку "Ни одна из перегрузок метода "GlobalMemoryStatusEx" не принимает "9" аргументов."?

Comment: Ну? Вы же передаете 9 параметров, а функция принимает 8. В чем проблема?

Comment: Ну и что мне сделать?

Comment: А вообще, каким образом вы передаете туда эти параметры когда неуправляемый код на самом деле принимает только указатель на структуру [`MEMORYSTATUSEX`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex)?

Comment: Вы тут всегда отвечаете на вопросы вопросами?

Comment: Чтоб я знал что нужно сделать, я бы тут не писал, согласны?

Comment: Покажите мне где ваш вопрос? Я его не вижу! Вижу только заголовок поста и код. Все.

Comment: Как мне убрать ошибку, что сделать?

Comment: @user276689 Вы сюда пришли язвить, я правильно понимаю? Советую вам 1. Научиться вести себя адекватно и отвечать на поставленные вам вопросы! 2. Задавать вопросы как можно подробней, что бы вас понимало как можно больше людей. 3. Начать обучение языку C# с основ, ибо вы полезли в WinAPI не зная основ, а если бы и знали, то вопрос такой не задавали! Прочитайте про методы, мой вам совет...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Думаете мне это надо? Мне в универе дали задание, я выполняю как понимаю. Нас там теории никакой не обучают, нам просто дают задание и время на выполнение. Дали неделю. Я как вник, так и сделал, а сюда я выложил в надежде что получится таким способом сделать, мне сказали что таким способом нельзя сделать и всё.

Comment: @user276689 Зачем вы тогда учитесь, если вам "это не надо"? Честно, давайте на чистоту, нас должно волновать то, что вам надо сделать задание и вас к нему не подготовили в университете? Мне (другим думаю тоже) совершенно не интересно то, что у вас там происходит. Не понимаете - удите к преподавателю, разъяснит. Наша задача увидеть вопрос, оценить, узнать более подробно о нем и ответить по мере сил, все. Вы же приходите сюда, задаете вопрос из за своей невнимательности и нежелания в этом разбираться (я именно про 8/9 аргументов), да еще и хамите окружающим. Как нам после этого к вам относится?

Answer (score 2):

Оффтопик:

> Для того что бы исправить вашу ошибку, вам для начала стоит почитать о
>   том что такое
>   [`P/Invoke`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke)
>   и как работать с неуправляемым кодом.

По делу:

Опишем неуправляемую структуру воспользовавшись [документацией](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-_memorystatusex):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MemoryStatusEx
{
    public uint Length;
    public uint MemoryLoad;
    public ulong TotalPhys;
    public ulong AvailPhys;
    public ulong TotalPageFile;
    public ulong AvailPageFile;
    public ulong TotalVirtual;
    public ulong AvailVirtual;
    public ulong AvailExtendedVirtual;
}
```

Далее описываем неуправляемый метод:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ref MemoryStatusEx lpBuffer);
```

Далее, в необходимом месте используем вот так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MemoryStatusEx memoryStatus = new MemoryStatusEx
    {
        Length = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MemoryStatusEx))
    };

    bool result = GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ref memoryStatus);
    if (result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total Physic memory {0}", memoryStatus.TotalPhys);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

Если вы не хотите описывать структуру, и хотите использовать только `out` параметры, то можно использовать вот такой извращенский способ с фейковой структурой:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx(IntPtr fakeStructPtr);

public static bool GetMemoryStatus(out uint MemoryLoad,
                                   out ulong TotalPhys,
                                   out ulong AvailPhys,
                                   out ulong TotalPageFile,
                                   out ulong AvailPageFile,
                                   out ulong TotalVirtual,
                                   out ulong AvailVirtual)
{
    int fakeStructSize = sizeof(uint) * 2 + sizeof(ulong) * 7;
    IntPtr fakeStructPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(fakeStructSize);
    Marshal.WriteInt32(fakeStructPtr, 0, fakeStructSize);
    bool result = GlobalMemoryStatusEx(fakeStructPtr);
    MemoryLoad = result ? (uint) Marshal.ReadInt32(fakeStructPtr, sizeof(uint)) : 0;
    TotalPhys = result ? (ulong) Marshal.ReadInt64(fakeStructPtr, sizeof(uint) * 2) : 0;
    AvailPhys = result ? (ulong) Marshal.ReadInt64(fakeStructPtr, sizeof(uint) * 2 + sizeof(ulong)) : 0;
    TotalPageFile = result ? (ulong) Marshal.ReadInt64(fakeStructPtr, sizeof(uint) * 2 + sizeof(ulong) * 2) : 0;
    AvailPageFile = result ? (ulong) Marshal.ReadInt64(fakeStructPtr, sizeof(uint) * 2 + sizeof(ulong) * 3) : 0;
    TotalVirtual = result ? (ulong) Marshal.ReadInt64(fakeStructPtr, sizeof(uint) * 2 + sizeof(ulong) * 4) : 0;
    AvailVirtual = result ? (ulong) Marshal.ReadInt64(fakeStructPtr, sizeof(uint) * 2 + sizeof(ulong) * 5) : 0;
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(fakeStructPtr);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Я так и сделал 1 способом. Я просто думал можно будет как-то другим сделать, который я сюда скинул, оказалось что нет. Понял вас, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Это значит что вы передаете некое кол-во элементво, которое не предвидино конструктором. Чтобы измбавиться от ошибки вам нужно передать нужное количество и нужного типа переменных. Для этого прочитайте [документацию](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.globalmemorystatusex)

Answer (score 0):

В определении функции указано 8  `out` параметров

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GlobalMemoryStatus")]
static extern void GlobalMemoryStatusEx(
    out long Length, // 1
    out long MemoryLoad, // 2
    out ulong TotalPhys, // 3
    out ulong AvailPhys, // 4
    out ulong TotalPageFile, // 5
    out ulong AvailPageFile, // 6
    out ulong TotalVirtual, // 7
    out ulong AvailVirtual); // 8
```

В вызове идет попытка в дополнение к этим 8 параметрам передать один входной:

```
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(
    disk, 
    out Length, // 1
    out MemoryLoad, // 2
    out TotalPhys, // 3
    out AvailPhys, // 4
    out TotalPageFile, // 5
    out AvailPageFile, // 6
    out TotalVirtual, // 7
    out AvailVirtual); // 8
```

Следовательно параметр `disk` лишний и его надо удалить:

```
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(
    out Length, // 1
    out MemoryLoad, // 2
    out TotalPhys, // 3
    out AvailPhys, // 4
    out TotalPageFile, // 5
    out AvailPageFile, // 6
    out TotalVirtual, // 7
    out AvailVirtual); // 8
```

Comment: Я удалял, всё равно не помогло

Comment: @user276689, не могло не помочь. Если ты получал какую-то другую ошибку - это должен быть уже другой вопрос.

Comment: ну да, там другая ошибка, мне там выше разъяснили, что этим способом не получится

Comment: @user276689, об этом я и говорю.